# Dual booting Linux and Windows 7 with an SSD?

Tags: windows-7, linux

I'm currently dual booting Linux and Windows 7 because while I prefer the development tools on Linux, a whole lot of games are Windows-only. At the moment booting into Windows takes about 1 minute and 15 seconds, while booting into Linux takes about 45 seconds. This is usually annoying to wait for. Therefore, I'm thinking of getting an SSD to improve my boot times. I have mainly two questions:

- What kind of boot time improvement is possible with, say, a $300 120GB drive?
- How much space should a clean install of Windows, together with a clean install of Ubuntu, take up?

Comment: It's hard to gauge something like boot time improvement since we don't even know what type of CPU, RAM, how wide the bus is, dedicated video or integrated, etc. All of these items need to be brought on line during boot and will vary your start up times. You might have a Promise SATA controller that takes 15 seconds to initialize. However, you will notice a big increase in start up going to a SSD. $300 for 120GB is soooo last month. Check out this 256GB Kingston for $220 - http://tinyurl.com/c79hnc6

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to throw this out there but http://download.cnet.com/Auslogics-Disk-Defrag/3000-2094_4-10567503.html can speed up your boot time significantly. It's a defrag tool but it has an optimize option that moves system files to the centre of your disk.

As for SSDs, which wont benifit from this. READ speed is most important for fast booting, and generally as more reads take places than writes.

My W7 installation takes up about 20GB of my 30GB SSD, you can reallocate the user folders etc to other hard drives to save space though.

Linux it depends, as much or as little space as you want.